# JavaFX 8 loading multiple fxml files into borderpane

Tags: javafx, fxml

Given the following code:

public class Main extends Application {

```
private BorderPane rootLayout;
private VBox toolbarLayout;

private URL path;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {                            

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();                

    // Root View

    path = getClass().getResource("mainLayout.fxml");
    try {
        loader.setLocation(path);            
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        

    // Toolbar View
    path = getClass().getResource("toolbar/toolbarView.fxml");  
    try {                        
        toolbarLayout = (VBox) loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    rootLayout.getChildren().add(toolbarLayout);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);        
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

If I comment out the second fxml 'try' the rootLayout loads fine. If I comment out the borderpane and set the toolbarView as the main view it works fine too.
BUT if I try to load the toolbarView into the rootLayout, the rootLayout loads fine, but the toolbarView throws an exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
```

Obviously I don't understand the fxml load process well enough, so can someone please throw some light on this? Why does it think I am trying to set the root again?

For completeness, here is the toolbarView.fxml:

```
<VBox fx:id="idToolbar" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity"
 maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
  prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="20.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

<children>
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
</children>
  <opaqueInsets>
    <Insets />
  </opaqueInsets>
<padding>
  <Insets top="20.0" />
</padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: For completeness, here is the fxml:

Comment: You can't reuse a single `FXMLLoader` for different FXML files like this. Just create a new `FXMLLoader` for each file you want to load.

Comment: That works - thank you. But why cannot the loader class be re-used? I thought that by resetting the location (loader.setLocation), it would simply load a new fxml I had that line before the second 'load', but took it out when that failed). Does each FXML loader keep a memory reference to the fxml file it loaded?

Comment: In short, because that's the way they wrote the API. I suspect that decision was made because each loading process relies on multiple interdependent properties (location, resources, controller), so it would be very easy to introduce hard-to-track bugs if you could reuse the loader.

Comment: And I missed the last part: yes, the loader keeps a reference to the structure loaded in the `root` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `root` property contains a reference to the structure specified by the FXML file; i.e. to the object created by the root element of the FXML file. Assuming you are not using the ["dynamic root" (`<fx:root>`) pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components), the root will be set as part of the `load` process to the object corresponding to the root element of the FXML. If it is not `null` at this stage (i.e. if it has already been set), then you will get an exception. A similar thing is true for the `controller` property: if the FXML file specifies an `fx:controller` attribute, the controller will be set as part of the `load()` process; if it is not `null`, an exception is thrown.

The `FXMLLoader` is really only designed to be used once, as you have many interdependent properties which are typically set as part of the load process: `root`, `location`, `controller`, `resources`, and elements of the `namespace`. So you should really create a new `FXMLLoader` for each FXML file you want to load:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();                

// Root View

path = getClass().getResource("mainLayout.fxml");
try {
    loader.setLocation(path);            
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
    e.printStackTrace();
}        

// Toolbar View

loader = new FXMLLoader();

path = getClass().getResource("toolbar/toolbarView.fxml");  
try {                        

    // note you omitted this line:
    loader.setLocation(path);

    toolbarLayout = (VBox) loader.load();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

rootLayout.getChildren().add(toolbarLayout);
```

It may be possible to reuse an `FXMLLoader` by carefully unsetting anything that has been set as part of the previous load process:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();                

// Root View

path = getClass().getResource("mainLayout.fxml");
try {
    loader.setLocation(path);            
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
    e.printStackTrace();
}     

loader.setRoot(null);
loader.setController(null);
loader.setResources(null);
loader.getNamespace().clear();   

// Toolbar View
path = getClass().getResource("toolbar/toolbarView.fxml");  

try {                        

    // note you omitted this line:
    loader.setLocation(path);

    toolbarLayout = (VBox) loader.load();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Not found: " + path);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

rootLayout.getChildren().add(toolbarLayout);
```

but this is really not the intended usage, and may not be robust to future changes to the `FXMLLoader` implementation.